# Building an HTML/CSS page but images won't load

Tags: html, css, image

I'm building my first website in HTML/CSS but for some reason none of my images show up when I load the HTML files in Chrome. When I hit F12 and go to the 'sources' menu, I can see that my index.html file (where the images should be loading) is creating errors saying the files can't be found (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND), even though I used Visual Studio's file picker to navigate to them instead of manually typing the addresses.

Here's a link to the file in case that helps provide more context (area in question is the box at the bottom of the page):
[redacted]/

I've tried clearing out my code from the css stylesheet, verifying the image addresses but unfortunately that's all I know to try at this point in my learning.

HTML for the box where I want to put the image background:

```
<div class="p-box">
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h2>Goodbye</h2> 
</div>
```

CSS for that box's class:

```
.p-box{
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
    background-image:url('/css/images/download.jpg'); 
   }
```

The goal is to get an image to load inside the 'p-box' container but nothing happens when I save and refresh the file in my browser.

This is my first site (and my first post here), so any feedback is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're loading an image from your drive instead of a local path for `check.png`

in your css, find this:

`list-style-image: url('E:\Desktop\HTML and CSS\CSS Tutorial Files\css\images/check.png');`

and change to

`list-style-image: url('/css/images/check.png');`

Here is some good information on learning about [file paths in the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Dealing_with_files)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you either figured it out or something else is blocking it on your side. I can clearly see http://[site name redacted].com/css/images/download.jpg has an image. I can as well see the bottom of the page that says Hello and Goodbye overlayed on the picture.

Best of luck with your project!

Comment: Oh wow, it wasn't working in Chrome but an incognito session shows it. I must have a cached version or something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a issue with where the html file is located. You might only need to change the url for the image to:

```
background-image: url('../css/images/download');
```

If your html file is inside the css folder or images folder it wont load correctly.

if all else fails just do this:

```
background-image: url('http://connerring.com/css/images/download.jpg');
```

Comment: I've actually tried changing the path a few times but it doesn't seem to fix the issue. I used the file picker in Visual Studio to make the path in the first place, but then it doesn't show up in the browser. Though, after AWBrown's comment I checked the hosted version in incognito mode and the image showed up, but it repeats instead of filling for some reason. (It also still doesn't show up in my local version)

Comment: if you want the image to fill the box you will need to use background-size: cover, which will fill the box the image is in.